# What does “I intentionally shorted you” mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

From *Better Call Saul*:

> PRICE : We're short . Twenty dollars, That's fine.
>       MIKE: Agreed amount or no deal.
>       NACHO :You serious? You saying I intentionally shorted you?
>       MIKE:No. Mistakes happen.

Is "shorted you" an idiom? or is it a common expression?

Comment: Yes and yes. It means to pay someone less than the agreed upon amount. The payment is said to be short of that amount, hence the verb.

Comment: I believe it's a contraction of "short-changed" http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shortchange

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Max. But I can't work out who is saying what in that dialogue of yours! I think perhaps the fourth and fifth lines should be concatenated.

Comment: Look up _short_ in a dictionary. Look under "verb".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's not all that easy to find the correct meaning in a dictionary (although the comments under the question probably should have helped quite a bit). Looking at *Merriam Webster* we find for [short](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/short), under *verb*:

> 1 :  short-circuit
>       2 :  shortchange, cheat
>       3 :  to sell (a security) short in expectation of a fall in prices

option 1 is about electricity, and not relevant in this case. The third option is about the stock-exchange, and not relevant either, although that may not be clear immediately.

The second option is what we are looking for. We can actually substitute *cheat* for *short* in the given dialogue without really changing its meaning.

If we look up [shortchange](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shortchange) we get:

> 1 :  to give less than the correct amount of change to
>       2 :  to deprive of or give less than something due

Where the second option is a more detailed explanaition of *cheat*.